# Mocking constructors using node and chai/sinon

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, chai, sinon

I have a function like this

```js
function buildToSend(repo) {
  const {
    name, ...data
  } = repo;
  return {
    msg: {
      application: data.name,
      date: new Date(),
    },
  };
}
```

And I need to test it but i really can't find out how to mock/stub the `new Date()`
 constructor.

Any ideas?

I already tried somethings like this but it didn't work.

```js
    const date = new Date();
    const myStub = sinon.stub(Date.prototype, 'constructor').returns(date);
    const input = {
      name: 'name',
    };
    expect(utils.buildToSend(input)).to.deep.equal({msg: {name: 'name', date: 'THE DATE'}});
```

I'm missing something but i really don't know what. (of course, date is not getting called that way)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [sinon.useFakeTimers()](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/fake-timers/)

> Fake timers provide a clock object to pass time, which can also be used to control Date objects created through either `new Date()`; or `Date.now()`; (if supported by the browser).

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
export function buildToSend(repo) {
  const { name, ...data } = repo;
  return {
    msg: {
      application: name,
      date: new Date(),
    },
  };
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { buildToSend } from './';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('60936845', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const date = 1483228800000;
    const clock = sinon.useFakeTimers(date);
    const input = { name: 'name' };
    expect(buildToSend(input)).to.deep.equal({ msg: { application: 'name', date: new Date(date) } });
    clock.restore();
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
  60936845
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (19ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```